# What is the mac equivalent of "/etc/apache2/sites-available"?

Tags: macos, apache-config

I am installing Koha from source. Generic unix directions indicate the following step after sudo make install

```
sudo ln -s /etc/koha/koha-httpd.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/koha
```

huh?

My apache2 directory contains no sites-available, only
/private/etc/apache2/extra
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/private/etc/apache2/magic
/private/etc/apache2/mime.types
/private/etc/apache2/original
/private/etc/apache2/other
/private/etc/apache2/users

I am supposed to be able to Browse to `http://servername:8080/` to run Koha, where I take it "servername" is specified in koha-httpd.conf as follows:

```
## Intranet
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.4:8080>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@local
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/koha/intranet/htdocs
   ServerName John-Breedloves-Mac-mini.local:8080
#  ServerAlias intranet.mydomain.com
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/koha/ "/usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/"
   ScriptAlias /index.html "/usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/mainpage.pl"
   ScriptAlias /search "/usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/search.pl"
   ErrorLog /var/log/koha/koha-error_log
#  TransferLog /var/log/koha/koha-access_log
   SetEnv KOHA_CONF "/etc/koha/koha-conf.xml"
   SetEnv PERL5LIB "/usr/share/koha/lib"
   Options +FollowSymLinks

   ErrorDocument 400 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/400.pl
   ErrorDocument 401 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/401.pl
   ErrorDocument 403 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/403.pl
   ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/404.pl
   ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/500.pl

   RewriteEngine On
```

However when I go to `http://john-breedloves-mac-mini.local:8080/`, I get:

## It works!

Which,is, like ironical or something.

Help a noob out.

Comment: Remember that OSX comes pre-installed with apache2, sitting at /etc/apache2. This can cause some pretty nasty overlap with *another* apache install.

Comment: That is the apache I am dealing with, I have not installed any other apache.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like `/private/etc/apache2/other/` would be the approximately corresponding folder. `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` contains a directive `Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf` that includes all files in that folder, much like the sites-available folder common on Linux installations of Apache.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.
Ok, so I modified the command to:
sudo ln -s /etc/koha/koha-httpd.conf /private/etc/apache2/other/
Restarted apache:
sudo apachectl graceful
And I am still getting no love. I am not sure what the problem is now at all.

Answer (score 6):

Run `apachectl -S` which is shorthand for `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

According to the apachectl man file, this will show parsed settings (currently only vhost settings). Incidentally, it also checks your config file for errors.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew's answer is correct.  On my install, I additionally had to change

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

to

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.

The fact that you're getting a server at :8080 indicates that you may be running a different apache config from the base system install, such as [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/); I don't believe that apache by default listens on :8080.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. It seems to occour because the default version of apache that is installed on osx over-rides other versions. to disable it go to "System Preferences > Sharing" and untick "web sharing".

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ServerRoot specifies where the subdirectories conf and logs can be found.

In my httpd.conf, it is set to /usr