# Access Koha Staff/OPAC client over LAN network

Tags: lan, apache-config

I've installed Koha 3.6 - as provided by Vimal Kumar on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. This works excellently.

However, I want to access the web Staff/OPAC client via LAN, so that I can open the clients on another computer (Windows 7) in addition to accessing it on the Koha machine.

Vimal directed me to this website: http://kohageek.pbworks.com/w/page/51840331/Network%20Configuration

Here is a break down of the instructions, and what I did. This method failed, and I reverted my files back to their original content, and my Staff/OPAC clients work again now, but are still not accessible on LAN.

I've got a router for this, and I connected each computer to the router - they can see each other on the network.

1) **sudo gedit /etc/hosts**
Enter the IP Address and Fully Qualified Domain Name

My original file contains the following:

> 127.0.0.1  localhost
>      127.0.1.1  ansa-desktop
>
> #The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts) 
>      ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
>      fe00::0 ip6-localnet
>      ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
>      ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
>      ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
>      ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

I replaced the top part with:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>      192.168.1.10    ansa-desktop

2) **sudo gedit /etc/hostname**
Enter the hostname of your system without domain name

My file contains the following:

> ansa-desktop

I didn't make changes in this file - it look right to me.

3)  In System --> Preferences -> Network Connections
Choose DHCP or Enter Static IP Number, subnet mask and gateway information

I chose the following:

> IP: 192.168.1.10
>      Subnetmask:255.255.255.0
>      Gateway: 0.0.0.0 (automatically set)

4) **sudo gedit /etc/koha/koha-httpd.conf**
Change the IP number in OPAC and Intranet virtual host.

My original file contained the following and the IPs in bold was subsequently swapped with my selected static IP (192.168.1.10):

> # Koha Apache Configuration Directives
>
> #NameVirtualHost *
>
> ## OPAC
>   '<'VirtualHost **127.0.1.1**:80>
>         ServerAdmin  webmaster@koha-desktop
>         DocumentRoot /usr/share/koha/opac/htdocs
>         ServerName koha-desktop
>      #  ServerAlias opac.mydomain.com
>         ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/koha/ "/usr/share/koha/opac/cgi-bin/opac/"
>         ScriptAlias /index.html "/usr/share/koha/opac/cgi-bin/opac/opac-main.pl"
>         ScriptAlias /opac-search.pl "/usr/share/koha/opac/cgi-bin/opac/opac-search.pl"
>         ScriptAlias /search "/usr/share/koha/opac/cgi-bin/opac/opac-search.pl"
>         ErrorLog /var/log/koha/koha-opac-error_log
>      #  CustomLog /var/log/koha/koha-opac-access_log combined
>      #  TransferLog /var/log/koha/koha-opac-access_log
>         SetEnv KOHA_CONF "/etc/koha/koha-conf.xml"
>         SetEnv PERL5LIB "/usr/share/koha/lib"
>         SetEnv MEMCACHED_SERVERS ""
>         SetEnv MEMCACHED_NAMESPACE ""
>
> ```
>   <IfModule mod_gzip.c>  
>     mod_gzip_on yes  
>     mod_gzip_dechunk yes  
>     mod_gzip_keep_workfiles No  
>     mod_gzip_can_negotiate yes  
>     mod_gzip_update_static No  
>     mod_gzip_temp_dir /tmp  
>     mod_gzip_minimum_file_size 512  
>     mod_gzip_maximum_file_size 1000000  
>     mod_gzip_maximum_inmem_size 1000000  
>     mod_gzip_handle_methods GET POST  
>     mod_gzip_item_exclude reqheader "User-Agent: .*Mozilla/4\..*\["  
>     mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*  
>     mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader Content-Type:image/*  
>     mod_gzip_item_include file \.js$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include file \.php$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/html$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include file \.css$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/css$  
>  </IfModule>  
>
>  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>  
>
>    # Compress content with type html, text, and css, ...  
>    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css  
>    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript  
>
>    DeflateCompressionLevel 9  
>
>    # Properly handle old browsers that do not support compression  
>    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html  
>    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip  
>    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html  
>
>    DeflateFilterNote Input instream  
>    DeflateFilterNote Output outstream  
>    DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio  
>
>    LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate  
>    <IfModule mod_headers.c>  
>       #properly handle requests coming from behind proxies  
>       Header append Vary User-Agent  
>    </IfModule>  
>  </IfModule>
> ```
>
> #  Repeat this virtualhost stanza changing the following environment vars to
>      #  create multiple OPAC interfaces with custom css and/or search limits:
>      #  SetEnv OPAC_CSS_OVERRIDE mystyle.css
>      #  SetEnv OPAC_SEARCH_LIMIT branch:CODE
>      #  SetEnv OPAC_LIMIT_OVERRIDE 1
>
> ```
>   Options +FollowSymLinks  
>
>   ErrorDocument 400 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/400.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 401 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/401.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 403 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/403.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/404.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/500.pl
> ```
>
> #  Rewrite Rules
>         RewriteEngine On
>
> #  Uncomment to turn on rewrite logging
>      #  RewriteLog /var/log/koha/koha-opac-rewrite.log
>      #  RewriteLogLevel 1
>         RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)(?:[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)=&(.*)
>         RewriteRule (.+) $1?%1%2 [N,R,NE]
>
> ```
>   RewriteRule ^/bib/([^\/]*)/?$ /cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail\.pl?bib=$1 [PT]  
>   RewriteRule ^/isbn/([^\/]*)/?$ /search?q=isbn:$1 [PT]  
>   RewriteRule ^/issn/([^\/]*)/?$ /search?q=issn:$1 [PT]
> ```
>
> ## Intranet
>       '<'VirtualHost **127.0.1.1**:8080>
>         ServerAdmin webmaster@koha-desktop
>         DocumentRoot /usr/share/koha/intranet/htdocs
>         ServerName koha-desktop:8080
>      #  ServerAlias intranet.mydomain.com
>         ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/koha/ "/usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/"
>         ScriptAlias /index.html "/usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/mainpage.pl"
>         ScriptAlias /search "/usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin/search.pl"
>         ErrorLog /var/log/koha/koha-error_log
>      #  TransferLog /var/log/koha/koha-access_log
>         SetEnv KOHA_CONF "/etc/koha/koha-conf.xml"
>         SetEnv PERL5LIB "/usr/share/koha/lib"
>         SetEnv MEMCACHED_SERVERS ""
>         SetEnv MEMCACHED_NAMESPACE ""
>         Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> ```
>   ErrorDocument 400 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/400.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 401 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/401.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 403 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/403.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 404 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/404.pl  
>   ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/koha/errors/500.pl  
>
>   <IfModule mod_gzip.c>  
>     mod_gzip_on yes  
>     mod_gzip_dechunk yes  
>     mod_gzip_keep_workfiles No  
>     mod_gzip_can_negotiate yes  
>     mod_gzip_update_static No  
>     mod_gzip_temp_dir /tmp  
>     mod_gzip_minimum_file_size 512  
>     mod_gzip_maximum_file_size 1000000  
>     mod_gzip_maximum_inmem_size 1000000  
>     mod_gzip_handle_methods GET POST  
>     mod_gzip_item_exclude reqheader "User-Agent: .*Mozilla/4\..*\["  
>     mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*  
>     mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader Content-Type:image/*  
>     mod_gzip_item_include file \.js$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include file \.php$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/html$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include file \.css$  
>     mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/css$  
>   </IfModule>  
>
>   <IfModule mod_deflate.c>  
>
>     # Compress content with type html, text, and css, ...  
>     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css  
>     AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript  
>
>     DeflateCompressionLevel 9  
>
>     # Properly handle old browsers that do not support compression  
>     BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html  
>     BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip  
>     BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html  
>
>     DeflateFilterNote Input instream  
>     DeflateFilterNote Output outstream  
>     DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio  
>
>     LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate  
>     <IfModule mod_headers.c>  
>       #properly handle requests coming from behind proxies  
>       Header append Vary User-Agent  
>     </IfModule>  
>  </IfModule>  
>
>   RewriteEngine On
> ```
>
> #  Uncomment to turn on rewrite logging
>      #  RewriteLog /var/log/koha/koha-intranet-rewrite.log
>      #  RewriteLogLevel 1
>
> ```
>   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)(?:[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)=&(.*)  
>   RewriteRule (.+) $1?%1%2 [N,R,NE]  
>   RewriteRule ^/bib/([^\/]*)/?$ /cgi-bin/koha/detail\.pl?bib=$1 [PT]  
>   RewriteRule ^/isbn/([^\/]*)/?$ /search?q=isbn:$1 [PT]  
>   RewriteRule ^/issn/([^\/]*)/?$ /search?q=issn:$1 [PT]
> ```
>
> servername localhost

5) Restart Apache    **/etc/init.d/apache2 restart**

This failed (I forgot the error message, but can recreate it if required).

I also have Webmin installed and configured, as part of the Koha install - if this should be relevant.

I have also looked at this article, but couldn't gleam from it a resolve for my problem:[stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121159/what-is-the-mac-equivalent-of-etc-apache2-sites-available)

If anyone can tell me why this didn't work and how to make it work, I would really appreciated it.

Thanks
Jurgens

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a koha specific question at all. It is how to get your apache server answering on your LAN.

First off do an sudo ifconfig

To find out what the IP of your server is. Then set apache up to listen on that address.

There is nothing special about Koha in this regards, it is just a website. So you just need apache2 answering on the IP number that is on your LAN. Not 127.0.0.1

Also webmin is not needed by Koha

Comment: I tried doing this but I can't access Koha. There's an apache page that says that there's no page in that address.

Answer (score 0):

You really dont need all these configurations, if you used the live dvd everything has been configured on it.

All you need to do is to go to your terminal and run an ifconfig to see the ip address on your  machine, it is this ip address that you will enter in the address bar on all other systems and they will see your Koha.

Answer (score 0):

Please do check if you have the same network on both of your koha server and client computer... In our case, koha is accessible via LAN using its ip addresses.

you may also need to check the network configuration itself. for example, if  your client pc cannot ping any request to the koha server then your network configuration might be the problem.

our koha work over LAN without any configuration on "koha-httpd.conf".