# How to install modules for Apache 2.4 (OSX)?

Tags: apache, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I installed apache with Homebrew.  When I start the default installation I get this error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 85 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load lib/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/var/www/lib/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so, 10): image not found

I went through commenting unfound modules out but it seems like it's missing all of them, especially useful ones like mod_auth_basic.  Looking at tutorials for installing apache with homebrew, I've noticed the paths it installed to on my computer are vastly different than what they are in the tutorial.

How do I install these modules (preferably with an all-in-one package as opposed to one at a time)?

Edit:

After looking at the error message for a second, I realized that the `dlopen()` is using my ServerRoot as the base for the modules.  Instead of

> dlopen(/usr/local/var/www/lib/httpd/modules/mod_auth_basic.so)

it should be

> dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_auth_basic.so

So how do I point the module loader to the correct directory?

Edit:

I solved the issue with modules not loading, but I would still love to know how to add modules.

Answer (score 0):

If your module dir is `/usr/libexec/apache2`, then you may need to disable SIP in order to be able to copy module file (`*.so`) there. The following discussion may help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really

Anyway, if you want more liberty with your httpd installation, you may want to download and build the source. It is quite simple and you can install it in any directory which is not protected (the suggested default is `/usr/local/apache2` which is fine) so you don't need to go through the hassle of disabling SIP.